# How to change a page's title when loading it in React without delay?

Tags: reactjs, page-title

I started learning React from Angular and I'm having trouble changing the pages'title dynamically, and I don't know if there is a better way of doing it than what I'm doing right now. I have, on each page, the following hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
        document.title = {title};
    }, []);
```

But with this hook I find a problem: there is a little delay (of a little less than a second) when navigating to another page.
Is there another way of doing this? (I've tried react-helmet but it still has that little delay)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need to change the page title synchronously (i.e., before the browser has painted the screen), you should use the useLayoutEffect hook. Here's an example:

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
   document.title = 'New Page Title';
  }, []);

 return (
  // your component code here
 );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
   document.title = 'New Page Title';
  }, [title]);

 return (
  // your component code here
 );
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Also, your code seems nearly identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75910756/466862), you certainly want to explain that difference.

Comment: the [title] in the useLayoutEffect is the difference that makes it works

Comment: Then _explain_ it, in the answer, not in the comments. And given the OP accepted the other answer, I doubt that difference is relevant.